# Meteor iron-router profile page refresh not working

Tags: meteor, refresh, iron-router

Goal: Be able to link directly to profile pages or refresh pages.

Problem: If you visit this profile page (https://pimp_stack.meteor.com/pevprofile/PqZrKZYTfy7EHfQei) you see the page for a few seconds, then you're rerouted to the home page.

> How to make stay on the profile page?

**The routing code:**

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  // render the Home template with a custom data context
  this.render('Home');
});

// Login / Logout
Router.route('/login');

Router.route('/logout', function () {
  Meteor.logout();
  this.render('Home');
});

  // given a url like "/pevprofile/<id>
Router.route('/pevprofile/:_id', function () {
  this.render('/pevprofile');
});
```

**The template code:**

```
<template name="pevprofile">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    {{> PevDetails}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="PevDetails">
  PEV Details
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to re-check this.  Its working fine on my end.  I'm seeing the profile page no redirection after several seconds.

[image: Screenshot]